# Updating original values after passing them as params to a new method instead of references

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have a method whose some parts of are repetitive. I managed to split the code in a way that the original method uses smaller methods many times. The problem is that when I pass some values as params to those new smaller methods and work with them, original values don't get updated. The actions I do are: value incrementation or removing items from arraylist. How do I update the original values using the smaller methods, not only the references? The only possible solution I came up with is to create a new class where I could have a setter for those values and update them. But are there easier/straightforward ways to solve it?

Part of the main method:

```
int numberOfBlocks = 0;
int currentBlock = 0;
int currentTime = 0;

ArrayList<Request> queue = new ArrayList<Request>();

if(queue.size != 0) {
    updateStatus(queue, currentBlock, numberOfBlocks);
}

if(something else happens) {
    removeFinished(queue, currentBlock);
}
```

Smaller methods:

```
private void updateStatus(ArrayList<Request> queue, int currentBlock, int numberOfBlocks) {
        if (queue.get(0).getBlock() > currentBlock)
            currentBlock++;
        else
            currentBlock--;

        numberOfBlocks++;
    }

private void removeFinished(ArrayList<Request> queue, int currentBlock){
        if (queue.get(0).getBlock() == currentBlock) {      
            queue.remove(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you pass a parameter in order for it to be changed in the method, your method should return the changed value, this will resolve your issue. If more then one value needs to be changed, then you are correct, primitives are passed y value and the invoking method doesn't see the changes made in the invoked method. So you should encapsulate those values in a wrapping class with setters and getters like you wanted to. That alone will resolve your problem. But also it would make sense for your method to return that class since it is modified. This is just a good stile

Comment: Thanks - and if I didn't want to create that new class for it, is it possible to achieve? Or should I stick to the class based solution only?

Comment: if it is just one value, then your method should return the updated value. That will solve the issue

Comment: In one case that will be alright, but in my second method I need to increment two values, so returning wouldnt work here.

Comment: So, then like I said, create a class that will hold those 2 properties with the setters and getters, pass it as a parameter, update it and return it.

Answer (score 1):

If the smaller methods are in the same class as the main method, simply don't pass them as parameters and the methods will use the class's fields. This is non-thread safe, but your class is non-thread safe already anyway.

```
class MyClass
{
    int numberOfBlocks = 0;
    int currentBlock = 0;
    int currentTime = 0;

    ArrayList<Request> queue = new ArrayList<Request>();

    void myMainMethod() {
        if(queue.size != 0) {
            updateStatus();
        }

        if(something else happens) {
            removeFinished();
        }
    }

    private void updateStatus() {
        if (queue.get(0).getBlock() > currentBlock)
            currentBlock++;
        else
            currentBlock--;

        numberOfBlocks++;
    }

    private void removeFinished() {
        if (queue.get(0).getBlock() == currentBlock) {      
            queue.remove(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've got more methods similar to the one I showed above which use the same primitives like `numberOfBlocks` but the values are different so I would have to create many fields, each for one method

Comment: Then like it's been suggested, when the method updates one value return it, when it updates more than one value return a class that contains all values updated.